# Deeplinking opens safari after trying some time objective c

Tags: ios

Applink opens app and works fine for some time
After that, the link starts opening the Safari and thereafter it never opened the app in iPhone 6 v(12.4.1)

I have added the domain in entitlement as applinks: www.example.com
is it something related to the AASA file or Safari?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check the help section (stackoverflow.com/help) for guidance on how to improve your question (for example showing us what you have attempted so far).

Comment: The domain entitled should be the link's domain. For example, if the link is http://www.myapp.com/bla the entitled domain should be applinks:myapp.com